# How to insert into a Service-based Database

Tags: c#, sql-server-express

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Dimmer\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Manage components\Manage components\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True");

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    SqlDataReader dr;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        cmd.Connection = cn;
        loadlist();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (txtid.Text != "" & txtname.Text != "")
        {
            cn.Open();
            cmd.CommandText = "insert into info (id,name) values ('"+txtid.Text+"'.'"+txtname.Text+"')";
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cmd.Clone();
            MessageBox.Show("Record instered!");
            txtid.Text = "";
            txtname.Text = "";
            loadlist();
        }
    }
}
```

I am new to C# and I have been trying for some hours with a insert code to a service-based database. I have tested the connection to it and it works.

I got this error message:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll
>
> Additional information: Incorrect syntax near 'xxxx'.

Where `xxxx` is what I insert into my 2nd textbox. The code stops at

```
cmd.ExcecuteNonQuery();
```

I have been searching for an answers for hours, I believe there is something wrong with the database.

Sorry if this code looks ugly, but I had some problems with spaces :P

Comment: What are the values of `txtid.Text` and `txtname.Text` exactly? And you should always use parameterized queries. This kind of string concatenations are open for _SQL Injection_ attakcs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't tell us what are `txtid.Text` and `txtname.Text` exactly but..

You should always use [`parameterized queries`](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html). This kind of string concatenations are open for [`SQL Injection`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

```
cmd.CommandText = "insert into info (id,name) values (@id, @name)";
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", txtid.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", txtname.Text);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Looks like you're reusing a connection and you probably have not closed it last time.

You should always close a connection immediately as soon as you're finished with it. Use [`using`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) statement like;

```
using(var cn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
using(var cmd = new SqlCommand(query, cn))
{
    if (txtid.Text != "" & txtname.Text != "")
    {
       cmd.CommandText = "insert into info (id,name) values (@id, @name)";
       cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", txtid.Text);
       cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", txtname.Text);
       cn.Open();
       cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
       cn.Close();
       ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello thanks alot for the fast reply! I did change the code to what you suggested and it brought me forward! I can see that my input is now recorded into the database but instead i get the error after input: An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: The connection was not closed. The connection's current state is open.

Comment: I would recommend not to use `SqlDbType.Text` - use `SqlDbType.VarChar` or something like that instead .... `TEXT` is deprecated ...

Comment: You are using  cmd.Clone(); instead of cn.Close();

Comment: @user3000443 Updated in my answer.

Comment: Thanks alot, I am starting to get this working. The problem I got now is that the parameters id and name is Always set. Even if i Close the Connection. I have tryed to use cmd.Parameters.Remove("@id") etc, but it wont let me set these to null.

Comment: OK I solved it with my code: cmd.Parameters.Clear(); in front of the other code. Thanks alot for all the help!